# Best practice for UDP python server handling many connections

Tags: python, postgresql, sockets, python-2.7, udp

I have a small server in python that receives UDP Packets from GPS devices.

Once data is received, it is decoded and then stored in a postgresql database.

How do I monitor the UDP packets?

I think that for some reason the queue is filling up to quick and some of the information is being discarded.

For some reason if I restart the daemon, the queue gets processed as it seems there is data still there. Is there a better way to handle this?

Maybe should I run multiple servers to decrease the load?

Or is there any setting to increase the size of the queue?

I am new to socket programming so please bear with me!!

Code as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, os, time

def main():
import socket
import struct
import sys, time
import psycopg2
import logging

try:
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    server_socket.bind(("myip", "udpport"))

    con = psycopg2.connect("conn info")
    cur = con.cursor()  

    while True:
        data = server_socket.recv(65535)
        #print data
        #print sys.getsizeof(data)
        logging.info(data)

        if len(data) is 34:
            # extract info
            info = struct.unpack("<hhBBchfflccccccccccccc", data)
            tid = ''.join([info[9] ,info[10] ,info[11] , info[12] , info[13] , info[14] ,info[15] , info[16] ,info[17] , info[18]])
            alarm = info[4]
            direction = info[5]
            longt = info[6]
            lat = info[7]
            speed = ord(info[4])
            fuel = ord(info[21])*2
            datasize = sys.getsizeof(data)
            messagetype = info[1]
            if messagetype == 8:
                dbmes = "cycle"
                keystatus = int(info[2])    
            elif messagetype == 3:
                dbmes = "alarm"
                keystatus = int(info[3])            

            try:
                # Update info on DB  
                cur.execute("update in database")

            except Exception, e:
                pass
        # Commit Changes to DB
        con.commit()

    cur.close()
    con.close()
except Exception, e:
    print "\n\nNothing to do. Daemon Already Running!!!!\n"

if __name__ == "__main__":
# do the UNIX double-fork magic, see Stevens' "Advanced 
# Programming in the UNIX Environment" for details (ISBN 0201563177)
try: 
    pid = os.fork() 
    if pid > 0:
        # exit first parent
        sys.exit(0) 
except OSError, e: 
    print >>sys.stderr, "fork #1 failed: %d (%s)" % (e.errno, e.strerror) 
    sys.exit(1)

# decouple from parent environment
os.chdir("/") 
os.setsid() 
os.umask(0) 

# do second fork
try: 
    pid = os.fork() 
    if pid > 0:
        # exit from second parent, print eventual PID before
        print "GREENCITY TANZANIA LTD GPRS SERVER PID %d" % pid 
        sys.exit(0) 
except OSError, e: 
    print >>sys.stderr, "fork #2 failed: %d (%s)" % (e.errno, e.strerror) 
    sys.exit(1) 

# start the daemon main loop
main()
```

Comment: The most important thing is that your data receivers should cope with database outages. They should buffer writes, recording to a local file before writing to the DB.

Comment: OK. So the solution would be to write the received data to a file or say an array, and then have a separate process that queries this file or array and subsequently stores it in the DB and deletes the entry?

Comment: That's my opinion yes. Otherwise when you inevitably have to arrange a short database outage, or have an unplanned longer one, you lose data.

Comment: But wouldn't writing to a file consume time and make the daemon lag behind anyway?